# Web-scraping with xpathSApply

Tags: r, xml-parsing, web-scraping

I am using doing some web scraping with packages XML and html, and I need to isolate the country name, and the two numeric values that you see below:

```
<tr><td>Tonga</td>

    <td class="RightAlign">3,000</td>

    <td class="RightAlign">6,000</td>


    </tr>
```

here is the code I've written so far - I think that I just need the right regexes?

```
# a vector to store the results
pages<-character(0)
country_names<-character(0)

# go through all 6 pages containing the info we want, and store
# the html in a list
for (page in 1:6) {
  who_search <- paste(who_url, page, '.html', sep='')
  page = htmlTreeParse(who_search, useInternalNodes = T)
  pages=c(page, pages)

  # extract the country names of each tweet
  country <- xpathSApply(page, "????", xmlValue)

  country_names<-c(country, country_names)
}
```

Comment: Can you post the URL of one of these pages? Without seeing the full page it's impossible to tell you what the correct XPath would be since, presumably, the page contains a few more table rows than the one you posted.

Comment: who_url <- "http://www.who.int/diabetes/facts/world_figures/en/index"

Comment: so an example page would be: http://www.who.int/diabetes/facts/world_figures/en/index4.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here no need to use `xmlSpathApply` , use `readHTMLTable` instead

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
page = htmlParse('http://www.who.int/diabetes/facts/world_figures/en/index4.html')
readHTMLTable(page)

                                              Country       2000       2030
1                                               Albania     86,000    188,000
2                                                Andora      6,000     18,000
3                                               Armenia    120,000    206,000
4                                               Austria    239,000    366,000
5                                            Azerbaijan    337,000    733,000
6                                               Belarus    735,000    922,000
```

using `xpathSApply` (Note the use of gsub to clean the result)

```
country <- xpathSApply(page, '//*[@id="primary"]/table/tbody/tr', 
                         function(x) gsub('\n','' ,xmlValue(x))
+ )
> country
 [1] "Albania        86,000        188,000        "                                                  
 [2] "Andora        6,000        18,000        "                                                     
 [3] "Armenia        120,000        206,000        "                                                 
 [4] "Austria        239,000        366,000        "                                                 
 [5] "Azerbaijan        337,000        733,000        "
```

EDIT As mentioned in the comment we can use xpathSApply without gsub

```
    val = xpathSApply(page, '//tbody/tr/td', xmlValue) ##gets a vector of table   
    as.data.frame(matrix(val, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)) ##transform to matrix
```

Comment: The query `val = xpathSApply(page, '//tbody/tr/td', xmlValue)` gets a vector of table entries, which might be turned (not quite perfectly) into a data frame with `as.data.frame(matrix(val, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))`